# Scaling/rotating elements based on scroll / element offset

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, parallax

The issue I'm experiencing can be seen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/daaYGw?editors=0010.

What I need to do is to be able to scale or rotate elements ( clockwise and reversed for rotating and scaling up and down ) based on scroll, sort of like a parallax effect. It works as expected for the first element, because it is positioned at the top of the page. But for elements that are positioned below, it does not work as expected, because the offset of the element from the top of the page is not factored in the calculation. I couldn't figure out how to do that. I want it to start rotating when the element is in the viewport ( I can do that myself ), but without the calculation factoring the offset, the element will be way out of position by the time the user scrolls to it.

I'm going to tag this as parallax, because I think its sort of like one, but if its not, please correct me. I also tried searching for the issue, but couldn't find anything, if you know something that can answer my question, please link to it. Thank you.

jQuery was added for simplicity, I think my problem is with the calculation itself and not with the library used.

```js
var $container = $('.container'); 
var winHeight = $(window).outerHeight(); 

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); 
  
  $container.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this); 
  var scroll = (scrollTop / winHeight * 4);

  $this.css({
    transform: 'translate(' + scroll * 2 + '%, ' + scroll * 4 + '%) rotate(' + scroll * 4 + 'deg)'
  });
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-left: 70px;
}

.container + .container { margin-top: 2500px; }

body {
  height: 10000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container"></div>

<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the offset of the element and calculate the difference with scroll top. When it's equal to `0` the element is touching the top edge so you can use this to activate the animation.

Here is a simplified example:

```js
var $container = $('.container');

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  $container.each(function() {
    var s = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()
    if(s<0) {
      $(this).css({
      transform: 'rotate(' + Math.abs(s)/4 + 'deg)'
     });
    }    
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-left: 70px;
}

.container+.container {
  margin: 200px 70px;
}

body {
  height: 1500px;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container"></div>

<div class="container"></div>
```

You can easily add an offset to start even before touching the top:

```js
var $container = $('.container');
var offset = 100;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  $container.each(function() {
    var s = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() - 100
    if(s<0) {
      $(this).css({
      transform: 'rotate(' + Math.abs(s)/4 + 'deg)'
     });
    }    
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-left: 70px;
}

.container+.container {
  margin: 300px 70px;
}

body {
  height: 1500px;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container"></div>

<div class="container"></div>
```